# How do deploy existing website on digital ocean?

Tags: deployment

I do not find appropriate instruction on how do deploy local drupal 8 website on remote server hosted on digital ocean. I found only on how to install new website but not putting existing. Does anybody deploy such a website?

Comment: The deployment process will depend on how the server is configured - ask your sysadmin how they set it up and what options you have available to deploy your site. Without knowing how the server is configured it's impossible to advise on how you can deploy to it

Comment: this is general digital ocean server. I created droplet, connected to shh, installed lamp. How do I put there my drupal code?

Comment: However you like, there's no single method to do it

Comment: I don't know any. On simple servers I used filezilla ftp but I do not see such option here

Comment: If SSH is working SFTP is likely an option. But this isn't the right place to get help with generally transferring files, we deal with questions that need knowledge of Drupal to answer. You haven't quite got to that point yet, you're still setting up the server